# My code gives me a no such element exception

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

```
public static void getBooks()throws FileNotFoundException{

  Scanner input = new Scanner(bookFile);
  String line = input.nextLine();
  int bookNum = 1;

  while (input.hasNextLine()) {
     bookNum += 1;
     line = input.nextLine();
  }
  input.close();

  input = new Scanner(bookFile);
  line = input.nextLine();

  bookarray = new String[3][bookNum];

  for (int y = 0; y < bookNum; y++){
     bookarray [0][y] = line.substring(0,10);
     bookarray [1][y] = line.substring(11,15);
     bookarray [2][y] = line.substring(17,18);
     line = input.nextLine();
  }
```

}

This code gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
    at BookInventory1.getBooks(BookInventory1.java:64)
    at BookInventory1.main(BookInventory1.java:15)
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:838]
```

pointing at the last

```
  line = input.nextLine();
```

line. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what is the input you have given?

Comment: Isn't the error message clear enough? you're calling nextLine(), and the file doesn't have any next line. Fix the code to avoid reading lines that don't exist.

Comment: Make your life easier: instead of using a `Scanner`, just use `Files.readAllLines()`

Comment: By looking at this error line - 'Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code ', it seems its a JVM bug & it is unpredictable. See this link http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6476706

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check -> input.hasNext()

Check this tutorial [scanner example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextline.htm) or read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) or checkout the specific javadoc for [next ()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29)

> NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are available

ex:

```
public static void getBooks()throws FileNotFoundException{

  Scanner input = new Scanner(bookFile);
  String line = input.nextLine();
  int bookNum = 1;

  while (input.hasNextLine()) {
     bookNum += 1;
     line = input.nextLine();
  }
  input.close();

  input = new Scanner(bookFile);
  if(scanner.hasNextLine(){
  line = input.nextLine();

  bookarray = new String[3][bookNum];

  for (int y = 0; y < bookNum; y++){
     bookarray [0][y] = line.substring(0,10);
     bookarray [1][y] = line.substring(11,15);
     bookarray [2][y] = line.substring(17,18);
     if(!line.hasNextLine()){break;}
     line = input.nextLine();
  } 
  }    

}
```